# What is the best way to animate tension?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I'm doing a tug of war animation where a rope is being pulled by both teams.  The rope should look like it has a lot of tension applied to it but I don't quite know where to start?

I tried applying a noise modifier to the graph editor but it still doesn't look quite right, it's shaking too much.  Is there a good way to animate tension because my method is what I've made up and I'm never right about these things.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a bezier curve, make a middle vertex, hook the vertex to something using ctrl+h (empty works best), use a medium noise on z location of the empty and a low noise on x or y so it moves left to right, and as the rope gets tighter reduce the strength of the z and decrease the scale so its movements are faster and tighter

If you want more detail just ask.

Comment: Do you think Scaling would be a bad idea?

Comment: A rope under tension gets very *very* slightly thinner and a bit longer.